# Cleaning up rejected migrations

Tags: discussion, migration, deleted-questions

The [system does not automatically clean up rejected migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243920) (questions sent here from another site, then closed here as anything except a duplicate).

Since rejected migrations are locked by Community♦, there's not much non-moderators can do about this (e.g. vote to delete) except flag.

I was thinking about going through these and deleting rejected migrations where:

- The question is **locked** and **closed** (not as a duplicate)
- It was **last active more than 6 months ago**
- There are **zero answers**
- The question is **not a migration *away*** from dba.se (the system handles these)

The [search query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+locked%3Ayes+answers%3A0+migrated%3A0+lastactive%3A...6m) I am using is:

```
is:question closed:yes duplicate:no locked:yes answers:0 migrated:0 lastactive:...6m
```

This finds **148 questions** at the time of writing. I review each one carefully before deleting. Can anyone think of any reason not to do this? Any other input?

Comment: My only input is to run it by the community team, to make sure they don't have any concerns. Otherwise, I am totally down with this. Don't mind helping either, so feel free to offload ;-)

Comment: @jcolebrand Very wise. I've asked in TL.

Comment: I wrote up an internal community request to do this automatically. However, due to time it will probably be a few weeks before this gets reviewed.

Comment: Now implemented; answer updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there were no objections, I have now completed this work manually.

Future rejected migrations will be [handled (mostly) automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287891).

> Starting this coming weekend, these should be deleted automatically 30 days after being rejected.
>
> Note that this logic will *only* delete a rejected, migrated question if it meets the following criteria:
>
> - Migrated from another site (and no moderator has cleared the migration history)
> - Not already deleted
> - Closed (but *not* as a duplicate)
> - Locked